# BroadcastReceiver declared in manifest is not receiving the Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I've tried to register a Wifi BroadcastReceiver to get the wifi state when it changes. But so far I have no luck receiving the broadcast.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    //activity declaration here...

</application>
```

Do you guys know how to register the BraodcastReceiver in manifest?

**I don't want to register it in activities** because I want to **monitor the wifi** when there is changes in the wifi state whether my application is running or not.

This is my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
        String wifiStateText = "No State";

        switch (wifiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLING";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLED";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLING";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLED";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            wifiStateText = "WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        MyLog.d(TAG, "onReceive Broadcast > WiFiState: " + wifiStateText);
        MyLog.d(TAG, "onReceive Broadcast > Time: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

I really hope to get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this Blog http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html

Comment: Have you defined permission for android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: @Ajay, I already looked at that Blog you mentioned. The problem is, like I mentioned, I want to register the receiver in the manifest NOT in the activities. I already put the permission in the manifest. Anyway, thanks for your attention Ajay.

Comment: @Zul please help me for the following Broadcast receiver ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989221/how-to-get-camera-click-event-with-the-help-of-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your receiver in manifest should looks like this

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also the following permission may be needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Wow..thanks @dong221. That really did it. If u don't mind me asking, how did you know that the action name must be 'android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED'? can you give me any link on that?

Comment: @Zul It's listed here as a constant value: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION

Answer (score 9):

If your Target android version is more than Android O. if you declare receivers in manifest they wont work. So you need to register inside your activity.

Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

Resource:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 3):

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
     <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
          <action
             android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"
             android:enabled="true" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Enter the high priority and also enabled flag as true

Comment: Wow..thanks @user1203673. That really did it. If u don't mind me asking, how did you know that the action name must be 'android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED'? can you give me any link on that? I'm sorry I cannot vote up, my reputation is not enough.

Comment: Try this: `<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>`

Answer (score 0):

Just because the broadcast was send with flag Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT, it means, your app must register this receiver before android boot up, which can only be the system services.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have registered the receiver like this way:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".WiFiReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="class name with package" />
        <data
            android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: '<data android:scheme="myscheme" />', I'm not following you. Any example on that?

Answer (score 0):

The best that worked for me:

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**WifiReceiver Class:**

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(info != null) {
            if(info.isConnected()) {
                //Do your work. 
                //To check the Network Name or other info:
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is all broadcast receiver related to the internet connection

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />                
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
```